# Auto generate Accessors and Mutators in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have worked on java with eclipse and its quite easy to generate setter and getter methods for every column of our database.
But with laravel (i am just 1 day old in it) , there seems no option to auto generate each model automatically with proper setter and getter methods of all fields.
1. How to auto generate all models in one command.
2. How to auto generate setter and getter methods for each model.

Is there any command or package i should checkout?

Comment: Why do you need to create accessors/mutators for every column? You just access the properties in the object directly.... you only need accessors/mutators if you need to customise properties

Comment: The Eloquent Model class has a magic getter and setter for accessing the attributes for you already.  `$model->id` is using the magic getter to get the 'id' attribute of the model.

Comment: @lagbox are not they private or protected?? i want to access them from my service class.

Comment: @MarkBaker  Its safe n easier to use methods to get and set data for Api request. Also i will be using service classes , so directly accessing variables won't be a good practice

Comment: The __get method and __set magic methods are public so they are accessible.

Comment: They're publicly accessible in the model instance whether you want them to be or not, unless you override the magic getter/setter with your own to render them inaccessible.... if you want to do that, then why are you even using Eloquent? But if you don't want them publicly accessible, why do you want to automatically create default mutators/accessors?

Comment: i didn't know about magic methods. Thanks to lagbox , i will try.   @mark baker  , ofcourse i want them to be  publicly accessible , but with encapsulation.Which i guess can be sorted out with _get and _set